# VBA Access 2010 extracting array elements as individual dynamically named variables

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba

I am working through an Access 2010 VBA script.  I am pulling information from a temporary table that may have 1 to 10 records in it.  I am using GetRows to build a two-dimensional array that looks like this, for example:

```
**0**       **1**
8677229     1
10289183    2
11981680    3
13043481    4
```

I have tested the array function by debug print, and the array does contain values.  I want to split out the array values dynamically into variables for later use.  In this example, I would like the 0 column to produce 4 variables named Anum(0) through Anum(3), and the 1 column to produce 4 variables named Pay(0) through Pay(3).   However, I keep getting a "Error 9, subscript out of range" where indicated below:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim PayAcct As Variant
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Anum, Pay FROM PayPerAcct")
Dim highval As Integer
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

While Not rs.EOF
   PayAcct = rs.GetRows(10)
Wend
highval = UBound(PayAcct, 2)

Dim Anum() As Variant
Dim Pay() As Variant

For i = 0 To highval
    'error occurs on the below line
    Anum(i) = CStr(PayAcct(0, i))
    Pay(i) = CStr(PayAcct(1, i))
Next i
```

When I manually define Anum and Pay variables and use the Cstr(PayAcct(1,0)) operation, it passes the expected value from the array to the variable, so I don't think that is the problem.

I suspect I am assigning Anum() and Pay() the wrong dimension, because I have seen similar example code in Excel VBA where defining those variables as Range works.  I have tried defining Anum() and Pay() as Range (which doesn't work, because this is Access VBA), Variant, and Object.

Any thoughts or tips?

Edit - 
The below ended up working, thanks for your help:

```
Dim Anum() As String
ReDim Anum(0 To highval)
Dim Pay() As String
ReDim Pay(0 To highval)
```

Comment: I am curious of your use of arrays. Unlike Excel, Access maintains a readily available indexed data structure called a table where you easily filter/search/condition values by IDs. I feel your end solution can be handled with a SQL query where the Jet/ACE engine is used instead of holding data objects in memory.

Comment: I am sure you are correct.  I haven't programmed anything in more than 20 years, and I am trying to figure out VBA as I go.  The end result of this procedure is to establish variables (Anum variables) to be tested against values in another array, keeping the one-to-one connection with Pay variables, so that I can insert the associated Pay value in a web form when the Anums match.  I couldn't figure out how to do it with the arrays themselves, and I couldn't figure out how to keep a connection between the Anum and associated Pay value in SQL, which is why I headed down this path.

Comment: You see, your needs can be handled with join SQL query. Use recordset here and inner join on Pay field of other array's recordset. Your Anum variables could just be `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could make a recordset out of data presented in  web form.  Looks like I have a lot more learning to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim Anum() As Variant
```

declares a dynamic array that hasn't any elements yet, so you can't assign values to it. It needs a `ReDim` to use it.

But since you already know how many elements you need, what you want is:

```
Dim Anum(0 To highval) As Variant
```

or if you know that you will only store strings in it,

```
Dim Anum(0 To highval) As String
```

Comment: I ended up dimensioning and then redimming the variables, as appended to my question above.  Thank you again for your help.